# Sumproduct division in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

When working in excel, to find the sum of the quotients of corresponding numbers in two sets, you use a function as follows:

=SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5 / B1:B5)

In google spreadsheets though, although the sumproduct function exists, it cannot do division like this.

In case you are not familiar with excel, this is basically what I want to achieve:

Column A: 5, 7, 3, 9, 4
Column B: 3, 2, 9, 8, 4

Result: (5 / 3) + (7 / 2) + (3 / 9) + (9 / 8) + (4 / 4)

Please note I am using google spreadsheets and not excel!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(A1:A5 / B1:B5))
```

[image]

Comment: Ahh, ArrayFormula, constantly having issues with this. Thankyou!